# How do I change the version number in the about window (Mac)

Tags: xml, macos, osx-mountain-lion, jnlp

Is it possible to change the version number displayed under "name of the application"-> About "Name of the application" in a Jnlp file? Right now is "Version 1.0 (1.0)" displayed which I can't find anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently do you have to bundle the program as a mac application, after that will the app display the info that is written in the info.plist file. This maybe isn't an answer to my question but the only solution I know.